# Receiving return None value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing exercise from the book where I am supposed to write program that can take a positive integer greater than 2 and write out the number of times one must repeatedly divide this number by 2 before getting a value less than 2.

```
def inStr():
n = -1
while n<2:
    try:
        n = int(input('Enter a positive integer greater than 2: '))
    except:
        pass
print(positive(n)) # prints None


def positive(n, step=0):
    if n < 2:
        # print(step) #it prints correct answer
        return step   #but why it returns None?
    positive(n//2, step+1)


inStr()
```

I don't understand why `def positive(n, step=0)` returns `None`?

Comment: It seems that you forgot to add `return` right before `positive(n//2, step+1)`?

Comment: thank you, should be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to add `return` right before `positive(n//2, step+1)`. So your function `positive` sometimes returns nothing (i.e. `None`).

Try this:

```
def inStr():
    n = -1
    while n<2:
        try:
            n = int(input('Enter a positive integer greater than 2: '))
        except:
            pass
    print(positive(n)) # prints None


def positive(n, step=0):
    if n < 2:
        # print(step) #it prints correct answer
        return step   #but why it returns None?
    return positive(n//2, step+1)

inStr()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you don't tell it to return anything else.  You need to put `return` in there:

```
def positive(n, step=0):
    if n < 2:
        # print(step) #it prints correct answer
        return step   #but why it returns None?
    return positive(n//2, step+1)
```

There may be times when a function calls itself, but *doesn'* want to return the results.  You need to tell Python that this time you want to.  Since you didn't tell Python what to return, it returns `None` by default.